# Load distribution using erlang

Tags: erlang

I have an implementation of a server that stores its information in a single data actor. Problem is that that this is not very scalable. What I want to do is distribute the load over multiple data actors, hereby sacrificing data consistency to my clients.

I want to be able to dynamically add nodes to my server in order to scale my application up, so I suppose I should have one data actor per node.

The problem is how to decide to invoke which node when. Talking through a "main server node" would imply a single point of failure and that's not what I want. I am new to Erlang and have read ["Learn You Some Erlang for Great Good"](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/) but that doesn't really help to give an idea on how to design the kind of application I want.

I am looking for pointers to educational example implementations/designs of the kind of system I want or ideas on how to get started.

P.S.: I know about mnesia, riak, ... but I can't use these systems.

Comment: Why can't you use mnesia?

Comment: The problem I see with your design is with "main server node". Why not make it peer to peer and use some algo for data sync, like gossip protocol ?

Comment: Instead of having a single server node defined upfront you could let all the nodes elect a leader that is responsible for the distribution of tasks.

Comment: Eric Redmond (Riak engineer) tackles some of the design issues you'll want to address: http://vimeo.com/68757697